# Как пакеты в протоколе TCP/IP узнают на каком сервере находится IP-адрес

Tags: маршрутизация, tcp-ip, провайдер

К примеру, есть несколько хостинговых компаний со своими ЦОДами, которые подключены к главным узлам (к ЦОДам крупных провайдеров) в городе, которые в свою очередь иду к магистральным линиям связи. И меня интересует, как пакеты узнают что IP-адрес находится на том сервере хост. компании а не на другом сервере другой хост. компании?

Вот я понимаю, что пакетам уже на выходе задан IP-адрес к которому они должны прийти. А как маршрутизаторы знают куда их направлять?

Comment: В маршрутизаторах есть таблицы маршрутизации, которые заполняются людьми. А ещё есть протокол BGP для динамической маршрутизации

Comment: Маршрутизатор выбирает оптимальный путь согласно таблицам маршрутизации. Вам для качественного понимания вопроса хорошо бы разобрать стек TCP/IP и модель OSI, а вкратце, в двух этих комментариях весь ответ.